# How to remove non-numbers from select query in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was selecting certain values from database, but unfortunately it end up with error `"Invalid number"`, so i suspect some non-numbers in columns. The interesting thing is, it is working in **oracle sql developer** ,but when it comes to the c# code it is throwing `"Invalid number"`, so strange , here is my query

```
select height+weight as total from tbl_human
```

So i changed to following query,but all becomes 0, how to correct it.

```
select  REGEXP_REPLACE('height+weight','[^0-9]+','0') as total from tbl_human
```

**EDIT**

height and weight are `varchars`

Comment: What data type are "height" and "weight"? Are they stored as strings, and not as numbers? Oracle has the bad habit of implicitly converting strings to numbers and performing arithmetic on the results, instead of just throwing an error to alert you that you are doing arithmetic on strings. Then: What do you want the result to be? If you have 178 in height (say in cm) and 'ABCD' in weight, do you want the weight to be converted to 0 and added to the height? Why? What is the real-life justification for that? (Instead of converting it to null, so that the result of addition is null too).

Comment: Also you talk both about "numbers" and "integers" - are the height and weight always integers? can't the weight be 74.5 (say, in kg?)

Comment: both are varchars in datatbase,but i need it as say 178.2 + 170.6 = 348.8

Comment: OK, so they may have fractional part. What should happen when you don't have a number in the field? Change it to 0?

Comment: yea,thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment. I have some questions:

- What datatypes are the `height` and `weight` columns?
- What do you expect to get from select statement? Give an example please.

---

As regards `REGEXP_REPLACE('height+weight','[^0-9]+','0')`.

What you are doing here is just replacing the string `'height+weight'` with `'0'` since `'height+weight'` matches regex `'[^0-9]+'`. 
You should use:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(height + weight,'[^0-9]+','0')
```

---

Edit:

I think this should work:

```
select  (CAST(height AS decimal)+ CAST(weight AS decimal)) as total from tbl_human;
```

Comment: That doesn't look too good, since height and weight may be individually non-numbers, so the code will fail at +, before it ever gets to regexp_replace.

Comment: @mathguy I agree, just wanted to correct use of `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov - that is not correct use of regexp_replace either. It only changes all the non-digits to the digit 0; the OP wanted to change the entire value to 0. What if a value is 123abc? That regexp will transform it into 1230, not 0.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov - do you have access to Oracle? SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer? Until you gain more experience, you should test your solutions before you post them. Your edit will throw exactly the same "invalid number" exception if the input is a string that does not represent a number (like '87.5 kg').

Comment: @mathguy I see, your answer encompasses all edge cases. Should be marked as Accepted. Still I don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: What is not working? You should point out what the problem is. `CAST( mycolumn AS decimal)` will work if `regexp_like(mycolumn, '^-?[[:digit:],.]+$')` returns true, otherwise you will get `ORA-01722: invalid number` error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want to catch values in either column (height or weight) that are not a number formatted as a character string. And you want to convert them to 0. You will have to do that on each value separately, before you add them (otherwise the addition will fail before you ever get to regexp_replace).

Here is one way. It assumes anything that is not a number should be converted to 0, even if for example in the `weight` column you have the value `'75.5kg'` - since this is not a number, it will be converted to 0.

Rather than show the full solution, I am just showing what needs to be applied to `weight` before being added up to something similar for `height`.

```
with
     inputs ( weight ) as (
       select '87.5'    from dual union all
       select '87.5 kg' from dual union all
       select '68'      from dual union all
       select 'abcd'    from dual
     )
select weight,
       case when regexp_like(weight, '^\d+(\.\d*)?$') then to_number(weight) 
            else 0 end as adj_weight
from inputs;

WEIGHT  ADJ_WEIGHT
------- ----------
87.5          87.5
87.5 kg          0
68              68
abcd             0
```

Comment: I am not getting what you said

Comment: Do you mean, you don't know how to use what I posted here in your code? To generate the `total` column you must `select (case when... else end 0) + (case when ... else end 0) as total from tbl_human`, where the first `(case ... end)` is exactly what I show (for WEIGHT) and the second `(case ... end)` is very similar, but should be for HEIGHT.

Comment: I am also saying that you must do this processing on weight and separately on height, and only then add the two results to each other. In your original attempt, you first added them to each other and then you tried to do something with the result. That can't work, the first thing the database engine must do is to add the two numbers, and if one of them is in fact not a number, the engine will throw an error right then and there, it will not even go further to see you were trying to apply some adjustments AFTER the sum was calculated.